# How to check user settings in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I have a user created by SQL command. I know there is the `getSetting()` function to check user settings. e.g. :

```sql
SELECT getSetting('async_insert');
```

But how to check other users' settings if you are a DBA? Is there any view/function/request for this purpose?

Comment: You know you can answer your own question, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually the `SHOW ACCESS` command showing user settings.